# Pass a handler to filter button property

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

So I have a handler for when I right click it , it will clear the criteria. How do I set this in setFilterButtonProperties? I want to be able to right click the filter button, it should clear all the characters I typed into the filter fields.

```
        addFilterEditorSubmitHandler(new FilterEditorSubmitHandler()
        {

            @Override
            public void onFilterEditorSubmit(FilterEditorSubmitEvent event)
            {
                if (event.isRightButtonDown())
                {
                    SC.warn("right clicked");
                    clearCriteria();

                }
            }

        });

setFilterButtonProperties();
```

Comment: Where is the issue, in clearing the criteria or adding right button click handler?

Comment: it doesnt clear either. And I am not sure how to add it to the Filter button

Comment: Are you able to capture the right click event? you want to clear the ListGrid critaria? Please confirm.

Comment: I got the message to display. But I dont know ho to add it to the filter button. And yes I want to clear the listGrid

Comment: I guess what I want to do is to create a "button" and pass that instance to setFilterProperties. The "button" is right click and clear all listgrid criteria. @Braj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Keep the functionality separate. There is no meaning of mixing two different tasks on the same button. Think from the end user's perspective.*

Don't use right click of the button because that's not common practice. How come the end user know about the new functionality until and unless hover is visible? As per the icon [image] that looks like to apply the filters, not meant for clearing the already applied filters.

*In short*, create a separate button that's sole purpose is to clear the applied filter. You can add the button in the *header/footer* as shown here in [Smart GWT Showcase](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#grid_components).

To clear the already applied filter simply call [ListGrid#fetchData()](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/grid/ListGrid.html#fetchData%28com.smartgwt.client.data.Criteria,%20com.smartgwt.client.data.DSCallback%29) again without passing any criteria means `null` on click of the new button.